# Como recuperar TOKEN de API Instragram?

Tags: ajax, api, instagram

He leido la documentación para generar los TOKEN, obtengo el user id y envio con POST los valores que me piden para obtener el tokken y el resultado es que me quedo atorado en la página del API de instagram ya con el API generado pero no retorna a mi web, intente con AJAX con el siguiente código:

```
<script>
    function Enviar(){
        var client_id=document.getElementById('client_id').value;
        var client_secret=document.getElementById('client_secret').value;
        var grant_type=document.getElementById('grant_type').value;
        var redirect_uri=document.getElementById('redirect_uri');
        var code=document.getElementById('code');

        var dataen = 'client_id='+client_id +'&client_secret='+client_secret+'&grant_type='+grant_type+'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+'&code='+code;
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
            data:dataen,
            success:function(resp){
                $("#respuesta").html(resp);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Pero no obtengo nada o mejor dicho no muestra nada, la pregunta es como recupero digamos el token o las variables que proporciona si el login es correcto usando AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

creo que no hay mucha actividad por aquí. Estuve buscando un poco mas de información sobre el uso del API de Instagram y encontré un código que me funcionó muy bien y es:

```
$client_id = '# de Cliente';
$client_secret ='# de Cliente SECRETO';
    $redirect_uri = 'URI Autorizada';
$code ='Código generado al iniciar sesión';

$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
$access_token_parameters = array(
    'client_id'                =>     $client_id,
    'client_secret'            =>     $client_secret,
    'grant_type'               =>     'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri'             =>     $redirect_uri,
    'code'                     =>     $code
);
$curl = curl_init($url);    // we init curl by passing the url
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);   // to send a POST request
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$access_token_parameters);   // indicate the data to send
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   // to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
$result = curl_exec($curl);   // to perform the curl session
curl_close($curl);   // to close the curl session
```

var_dump($result);

Esto me devuelve en pantalla todos los parámetros del API de Instagram como lo son el acceso token, usuario y la información básica que proporciona el API en su uso mas sencillo.